# exchange array number elements to strings from other array

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
current_month = datetime.date.today().month
last_months = [(current_month - i - 1) % len(months) + 1 for i in range(7)]
```

I want to exchange `last_months` array numbers to strings from `months`.
How can i do that ?

Thank for help in advance.

Comment: `[months[i] for i in last_months]`?

Comment: Whilst the direct answer is as written below, you'd be better off just looking at the answers from the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the indexer part of your `last_months` inside an array lookup.

```
[months[(current_month - i - 1) % len(months) + 1] for i in range(7)]
```